# How to create a soap message by using wsdl url?

Tags: java, web-services

I am new to webservices.i have the following wsdl file by using that i need to create a soap message can any one please help me out ?
wsdl-https://demo.iduws.tracesmart.co.uk/v3.4/?wsdl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some tool like `SoapUI`, which can generate sample message for each operation in web service interface.

In Java application I recommend to generate web service client, you can use  `JAX-WS`, `Apache Axis`, `Apache Axis 2` or `Apache CXF` libraries for working with SOAP Web services.

All IDEs have support for web service client generation. For eclispe some tutorial is here http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_client.html.
SoapUI supports client generation too.

Answer (score 0):

Generate java classes from the wsdl link. here is an example [link](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/)
then as usual call the webservice method by [click here](http://www.javaexperience.com/generate-soap-web-service-client-using-wsimport/)